# Kronecker product of two block diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider two block diagonal matrices
$$\mathbf A = \begin{bmatrix}
A_{1} & O\\
0 & A_{2}
\end{bmatrix} 
\mathbf B = \begin{bmatrix}
B_{1} & O\\
0 & B_{2}
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
$A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2$ have same dimension(may not necessary).
Could we show after some row and column permutations of $\mathbf A\otimes \mathbf B$, it will be same as $diag\{A_1\otimes B_1, A_2\otimes B_1, A_1\otimes B_2, A_2\otimes B_2\}$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Note that

$$A\otimes B=\begin{bmatrix}A_1\otimes B&O\\O&A_2\otimes B\end{bmatrix}$$and $$A_i\otimes B=\begin{bmatrix}A_i\otimes B_1&O\\O&A_i\otimes B_2\end{bmatrix}$$which are direct consequences of the Kronecker product.

Comment: Maybe the second equation is not "equal" but "permutation equivalent"

Comment: Can you give me some references on this comment?